# Why does a glass acts like a mirror in viewed at an angle?

Tags: optics, optical-materials

There is a conference hall , glass door parallel to my desk. whenever  the door is open, I can see reflection of images perpendicular to the viewing angle. But when the door is closed, I can’t see any reflection but see thru.

Why transparent glasses acts as a mirror viewed at certain angle?

One thing I noticed is, the reflection is seeing when the back side of the glass is darker than its surroundings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does a window become a mirror at night?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21075/)

Comment: Check the Wikipedia article on [Fresnel equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) which has a plot of surface reflectivity versus incidence angle. These equations, though, only give phenomenological explanation. On the physical side, I believe that at large incidence angle the electromagnetic wave cannot polarize the glass properly to induce propagation of the electromagnetic wave.