# Why does glass/plastic reflect with a dark background

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, reflection

This might be a possible duplicate( I couldn't find a similar question though). 
While travelling through trains/cars, we often pass through non-luminous  patches,as in tunnels or even at night. What I noticed, was that in such cases, the glass tends to act more like a mirror. I can partially see outside, and partly see my own reflection.

To generalise this observation: A transmitting medium like glass or plastic sheets, tend to behave like mirrors, whenever there is an imbalance in illumination on its opposing transmission surfaces, the light being reflected on whichever side there is a higher illumination. Is this statement correct by and large? And what could be the reason to it?
Thanks!

Comment: The reflective properties of the glass don't change based on the illumination. The reflection of your face was there when you were driving in a bright place too, but it's much harder for your eyes to pick out the weak reflection when there is strong light coming in from outside. When the outside light is weak, it's easier for your eyes to make out the reflection.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21075/2451 and links therein.

Comment: See also: [How does a one-sided glass work?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101380/how-does-a-one-sided-glass-work)